# Can't locate object method "am_pm_abbreviated" via package "DateTime::Locale::en"

Tags: perl, datetime, locale, strptime

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Can't locate object method "am_pm_abbreviated" via package "DateTime::Locale::en" at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm line 777.

Thanks,
Sun

Comment: It would probably help if you showed us what you were doing to get that error. It's early in the day and my telepathy hasn't really kicked in yet.

Answer (score 3):

Your version of [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime) probably expects a newer version of [DateTime::Locale](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aLocale) than the one you have installed. Upgrade it.